# How to avoid duplicate data feed into a sqlite database in python?

Tags: python, sqlite, dataframe, duplicates

Is there any convenient method in python to avoid duplicate data feeding into a database?

1. intend to feed a big chunk of data fetched from internet in dataframe type into an sqlite database
2. don't want to use sql insert command for the check. considering it is per-row-based check, I don't think it is efficient enough.

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with python, but i have done simple database design.
You can use contraints during table creation to control your data.

For example Unique contraint - It ensure all the data in column is unique :

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
ID int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Age int,
UNIQUE (ID));
```

Or

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
ID int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Age int,
CONSTRAINT UC_Person UNIQUE (ID,LastName));
```

There are other contraints also like

1. NOT NULL - Ensures that a column cannot have a NULL value
2. PRIMARY KEY - A combination of a NOT NULL and UNIQUE. Uniquely identifies each row in a table
3. FOREIGN KEY - Uniquely identifies a row/record in another table
4. CHECK - Ensures that all values in a column satisfies a specific condition
5. DEFAULT - Sets a default value for a column when no value is specified
6. INDEX - Used to create and retrieve data from the database very quickly